# Custom alert dialog is shown different in older Api's

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

[When I run my device on API 23
I get this alert dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AajM.png)

[But On API 23 I got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf6DZ.png)

I used this code

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertaialog);

final TextView alertmessage = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertmessage);
final TextView alert = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
final Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertbutton);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below line. It will solve your problem.

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Actually, you have to hide the title place of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It may happens default themes behave different in different android Version, You should define themes also while creating Dialog class object like

`final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);`

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AppCompatDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html) for consistent, Material theming across devices.